# How to close java application after uploading file

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have a test to upload one file and then upload another file.

When first file is uploaded, java application is opened:
[image]

Steps to upload file:

- click on upload button 

- using robot and keyPress, keyRelease to open file

But then I could not upload another file.

If close Java application manually, everything works Ok.

How to close it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

On Unix, you can kill an application by name:

```
pkill [process name]
```

On Windows, you can use *taskill*:

```
taskkill /F /IM <processname>.<extension>
```

And to run it programmatically:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pkill [process name]")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You have to quit driver in `tearDown` mehthod with `@AfterMethod` annotation but there is few more things need to keep in mind like your test cases should be separate for each file upload and browser launch should be in `setUp` method. Please have a look below code to achieve it.

```
    @BeforeMethod
      public void setUp() 
      {     
      // Launch browser here   
      }


    @Test
    public void uploadFirstFile()
    {
    // test case1
    }
     

    @Test
    public void uploadSecondFile()
    {
    // test case2
    }

   // Close the driver or exit the application

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() 
      {         
          driver.quit();
      }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: He is not talking about the Chrome browser, but the Java app on the right side of the image.